# Pycharm - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, pycharm

I installed the package sqlalchemy with Pycharm

[image]

Run program: `python datagenerator` and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "datagenerator\__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import database
  File "datagenerator\database.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

The directory it is in is a source root.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql://matt:database@localhost/test")
Session = sessionmaker()
```

I had the same issue with another module too.

**main:**

```
import sys, argparse
import database
from generator import Generator
from funcmodule import my_function


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
    parser.add_argument('--s', dest='s', nargs='+')
    parser.add_argument('--u', dest='u', nargs='+')
    parser.add_argument('--c', dest='c', nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.series:
        database.series()
```

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with a different library (a customised one).  We're banned from using virtual environments at my work, and I'm the only one with this problem.